# How to laod softkeyboard sticker/gifs into imageview using android studio. like whatsapp,imo,etc

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I am a Android application developer, I have implemented a chat feature in my app. I want to integrate the stickers/gifs available in the soft keyboard into my app's chat interface, similar to how WhatsApp and IMO handle it.

Even if a user uses any soft keyboard like Gboard or Google AI Keyboard, apps like WhatsApp still allow users to add stickers from those keyboards to their chats. I want to implement similar functionality in my app.

I need code to load stickers/gifs from the soft keyboard into an Imageview using android studio java language. Could you provide me with the code for this, or explain how to implement it? I have attached screenshots for reference.

Attachment 1 -  [image: Showing soft keyboard stickers/gifs]
Attachment 2 -   [image: Clicking on a sticker then displaying it in the chat (Sticker shown in ImageView)]

I want code for this development or explain how to implement it?